# 和製【わせい】、和語【わご】。。。わt's the diff?

Tags: meaning

So looking it up it translated to 和製 means "Japanese made" and 和語 means "Native Japanese".

But aren't native Japanese words Japanese made (not taken from Chinese)?

Comment: I hope the `わt's the diff` hiragana was intentional.  XD

Comment: @istrasci of course! ;)

Comment: +1 for that わt's the difference. lol

Answer (score 3):

和製 is typically used in the phrase 和製英語, 'Japanese-made English'. This refers to English words and phrases coined in Japan, often with meanings that aren't clear to native English speakers. Think of things like 'office lady', '2LDK', 'jet coaster', and so on.

和語 is, as you say, typically used to mean native Japanese vocabulary. I'm more used to seeing that called 大和言葉, but 和語 means mostly the same thing.

Comment: Why can't the Japanese not derived from Chinese be 和製日本語 then?

Comment: 大和 refers to ancient Japan, which should already sufficiently explain native Japanese (words, in the case of 大和言葉).

Comment: @Y12K 和製日本語 sounds to my ears like someone going excessively far out of their way to emphasise the native Japaneseness of native vocabulary. It sounds like what someone would say if they're a nationalist wanting to rid Japanese of all foreign words, kango included, and make some sort of 'pure Japanese Japanese'.